Azure App Gateway, App Services and Database for MySQL Server - Disable public access on App Services
In Azure I currently have an Application Gateway, two App Services and two Azure Database for MySQL Servers.
The two MySQL Database Servers have public access disabled, so it can only be reached through the App Service and/or the VNet.
Now, I would like the two App Services not to be able to be accessed by public as well, so with public access disabled. I have tried different options to do this, but I keep getting a “502 Bad Gateway” error when accessing the App Services both internal as external.
Below some more information:
VNET (192.168.100.0/22)
Subnet App_Gateway_V2 (192.168.101.80/28)
Subnet AppSvcSubnet (192.168.102.0/24)
Subnet PrivateLinkSubnet (192.168.103.0/24)
None of the subnets are linked to a NSG.
Application Gateway has both Frontend Public as Private IP.
Private IP = 192.168.101.84
Public IP = 108.xxx.xxx.xx
The App Services have the VNet Integration enabled for outbound traffic (AppSvcSubnet).
The Azure Database MySQL Servers have public access disabled and have a Private Endpoint configured. The Private Endpoint has subnet PrivateLinkSubnet. When opening the Private Endpoint, it also has a Private DNS zone (privatelink.mysql.database.azure.com) with IP-address 192.168.103.5
The above is the current situation as it is now.
Like I mentioned, I would like to disable public access on the App Services as well now.
What I tried is creating a Private Endpoint as Inbound traffic for the App Service (PrivateLinkSubnet with Private DNS zone enabled (192.168.103.20).
For the Access Restrictions I selected the option: Public network access - Enabled from select virtual networks and IP addresses. Then, in the allow rules I added the following rules:
Allow AppGw Traffic (192.168.101.84/32)
Allow AppGw Traffic (108.xxx.xxx.xx/32)
Allow VNET Traffic (192.168.100.0/22)
However, with the above configuration I can still access the Web App both internal as external. When removing the rule Allow AppGw Traffic (108.xxx.xxx.xx/32), I cannot reach the Web App anymore both internal and external. I receive the “502 Bad Gateway” error.
Does someone know what I’m doing wrong or how I can configure it correctly?
Thank you in advance.

Can you please share a network diagram for the configuration? This will make it easier to understand your requirements.

@VenkatV how can I generate the network diagram? Or do you mean that I have to create it myself?

The 502 Bad Gateway error occurs when trying to access the app service via the Application Gateway's public IP because the Application Gateway is unable to communicate with the app service.

To resolve the issue, you may need to enable Selected Networks in the App Service networking settings and add the Application Gateway's public IP. This is a valid approach. Alternatively, you can disable public access to the App Service and enable a private endpoint with a valid Private DNS zone configuration.


I would like the two App Services not to be able to be accessed by public as well, so with public access disabled. I have tried different options to do this, but I keep getting a “502 Bad Gateway” error when accessing the App Services both internal as external.

The 502 Bad Gateway error occurs when trying to access the app service via the Application Gateway's public IP because the Application Gateway is unable to communicate with the app service.

To resolve the issue, you may need to enable Selected Networks in the App Service networking settings and add the Application Gateway's public IP. This is a valid approach.
Alternatively, you can disable public access to the App Service and enable a private endpoint with a valid Private DNS zone configuration.

App Service Private Endpoint DNS Configuration

Virtual Network link configuration

When I try to access the App Service URL via the public network, it's throwing an error as expected.

Application Gateway configuration

App service is accessible via application gateway Public IP

To enable communication between the app service and the SQL Server database, you can enable a private endpoint for the MySQL database, allowing them to communicate with each other securely.

thank you for your reply. I have configured it exactly the same way as you, but when accessing the App Service via application gateway Public IP I am getting a 404 Not Found error.

Can you please share the application gateway backend health screenshot.

Backend health: i.imgur.com/OpSxg6S.png Backend settings: i.imgur.com/461C9Li.png

@Uhmazing34,   A 404 error seems to be an application issue. You can check the application by enabling public access. If the application still doesn't work, create another app with a private endpoint and add it to the Application Gateway

I have currently set the App Service Public network access to: Enabled with restrictions (Enabled from select virtual networks and IP addresses). Then, in the allow rules I added the VNet and the Private IP + Public IP of the Application Gateway.
After applying, when I go to the Default Domain of the web app from my own IP/computer, it shows "Error 404 - Forbidden. The web app you have attempted to reach has blocked your access." So this is correct I guess. (1/2)

But when I go to the custom domain from my own IP/computer, I can still access it. Is that because in the Application Gateway I defined the custom domain in the listeners? And because I added the public IP of the Application Gateway as allow rule? (2/2)

Is this your requirement?
**Access custom domain (in AppGw) - works, **
Access App Service directly - give 404 (blocked, that is excepted scenario.

If it works with the Application Gateway's public IP but not with the web app URL, that is an expected scenario. I hope this helps resolve your query.

When I go to the Application Gateway's Frontend Public IP in a browser, I get a 404 not found. Is that because the Application Gateway has two web apps? I have multiple listeners (HTTP + HTTPS for each web app). In the listeners I set the host name to the custom domain URL (not the default domain URL from the App Service).
So: when accessing Web App default domain URL from my own computer: I get an Error 403 - Forbidden. When accessing Web App custom domain URL (that is mentioned in listener) I can access the Web App.

If you are able to access with Web App default domain URL, and not from custom domain url, there might be issue with custom domain configuration.

If your web app is configured with custom domain and accessible with custom domain url, you can add the same custom domain url backend pool section instead default URL. Looks like network setup is fine

In the backend pool section I currently have: App Services -> Selected my App Service
Should I change this into "IP address or FQDN" and fill in the custom domain URL in the target box?

If web app is working with custom domain. URL,add the same URL by selecting FQDN option

when accessing Web App default domain URL from my own computer: I get an Error 403
Because you whitelisted only App GW PIP in the App service settings.
If you whitelist your own computer's IP, you can able to access from your computer.
When accessing Web App custom domain URL (that is mentioned in listener) I can access the Web App.
You make request to App gw with your IP
App GW makes a request to App Service with App Gw's PIP - which is whitelisted
And hence this is working (as expected)

Thank you @Venkat V, then I guess my problem is solved!
